# C# equivalent to TypeScript Template Literal Types?

Tags: c#, typescript, types

So I have a C# function that accepts a SQL sort order parameter:

```
public static string BuildSortClause(string colId, string sortOrder) {
   ...
}
```

I only want to accept 'ASC' or 'DESC' as valid sortOrder strings during compilation. Any other string passed in should fail. In Typescript this would be easy, I would just use a Template Literal Type for that parameter:

```
type SortOrder = 'ASC' | 'DESC';
```

What is the closest solution to this sort of string type restriction in C#?

Comment: An enum or a static class with fixed members would be the closest, but C# has no direct support for this case.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with an enum and the default `ToString` method.

```cs
public enum SortOrder { Asc, Desc }

public static string BuildSortClause(string colId, SortOrder sortOrder) {
   // string sort = sortOrder.ToString(); //either "Asc" or "Desc"
   ...
}

public static void Do() {
   BuildSortClause("someId", SortOrder.Asc);
}
```